# Can't access the external network from pod (nginx-pod)

Tags: kubernetes

I can't access externel network from inside the pod (i.e curl google.com) it shows `error curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com.`

I created single node kubernetes cluster and created the nginx pod, I tried to access externel network from pod but its not working showing like this

```
root@kube-master-1 ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-pod   1/1     Running   0          19s

[root@kube-master-1 ~]# kubectl exec -it nginx-pod -- sh
# curl google.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
```

I also checked the coredns it also show some error

```
[root@kube-master-1 ~]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-57b57c56f-t4n58   1/1     Running   0          10m
calico-node-2fskd                         1/1     Running   0          10m
calico-node-mpz67                         1/1     Running   0          10m
coredns-787d4945fb-hl8h7                  1/1     Running   0          10m
coredns-787d4945fb-k47hg                  1/1     Running   0          10m
etcd-kube-master-1                        1/1     Running   0          10m
kube-apiserver-kube-master-1              1/1     Running   0          10m
kube-controller-manager-kube-master-1     1/1     Running   0          10m
kube-proxy-djwpf                          1/1     Running   0          10m
kube-proxy-z6wbs                          1/1     Running   0          10m
kube-scheduler-kube-master-1              1/1     Running   0          10m

[root@kube-master-1 ~]# kubectl logs coredns-787d4945fb-hl8h7 -n kube-system
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration SHA512 = 591cf328cccc12bc490481273e738df59329c62c0b729d94e8b61db9961c2fa5f046dd37f1cf888b953814040d180f52594972691cd6ff41be96639138a43908
CoreDNS-1.9.3
linux/amd64, go1.18.2, 45b0a11
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6411469028493896089.8637463944530651356. HINFO: read udp 10.85.0.4:38789->172.168.9.1:53: read: no route to host
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6411469028493896089.8637463944530651356. HINFO: read udp 10.85.0.4:51289->172.168.9.1:53: read: no route to host
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6411469028493896089.8637463944530651356. HINFO: read udp 10.85.0.4:58043->172.168.9.1:53: read: no route to host

[root@kube-master-1 ~]# kubectl logs coredns-787d4945fb-k47hg -n kube-system
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration SHA512 = 591cf328cccc12bc490481273e738df59329c62c0b729d94e8b61db9961c2fa5f046dd37f1cf888b953814040d180f52594972691cd6ff41be96639138a43908
CoreDNS-1.9.3
linux/amd64, go1.18.2, 45b0a11
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 7329724478827996615.6993984998633749254. HINFO: read udp 10.85.0.3:50475->172.168.9.1:53: read: no route to host
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 7329724478827996615.6993984998633749254. HINFO: read udp 10.85.0.3:34954->172.168.9.1:53: read: no route to host
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 7329724478827996615.6993984998633749254. HINFO: read udp 10.85.0.3:54015->172.168.9.1:53: read: no route to host.
```

give me the possible way to resolve my issues

Comment: have you tried following [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/). Also make sure to disable firewall and open up all the required ports

Comment: not resolve it shows same thing the problem is with coredns 
read udp 10.85.0.4:38789->172.168.9.1:53: read: no route to host

Comment: Are you running a private cluster? Did you setup NAT?